# Android 2.2. Portrait Camera Preview

Tags: android, camera, orientation

I'm working on an Android app that shows a camera preview.  Ideally I'd like the app to work in portrait mode, which means I need to deal with rotation of the camera preview image.

I only need to support API level 8 (Android version 2.2) and up, so I can use [Camera.setDisplayOrientation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation%28int%29) to set the orientation, and the API docs for that method include a setDisplayOrientation function that does what I want.  The only problem is that it uses the API Level 9 [Camera.CameraInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.CameraInfo.html) to get the orientation of the camera with respect to the device (presumably to deal with landscape vs portrait devices).

So is it safe to assume that I can do setDisplayOrientation(90) for all level 8 devices and just use CameraInfo.orientation for newer devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a follow up for anyone else finding this - I didn't find a definitive answer on this, so I did as I suggested above (setDisplayOrientation(90)) for 2.2 devices and released the app.  It's had about 70,000 downloads and no reports of the camera display being wrongly rotated by 90 degrees, so it looks like this is a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried the following on an HTC Evo Shift with a project set to API8 (worked great):

```
Configuration cfg = mContext.getResources().getConfiguration();
if (cfg.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
    mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting the link to Android's developers help in the Camera matter:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

About your question in specific, i took a look at the API and i guess, since the surfaceChanged method is called every time a change in surface is made and the equipment have only 2 position, you are probably right, since u implement the corrected methods in the surfaceChanged method. Try to implement it and if you can't get it to work post the problem and i'll try to help more.

Comment: My question is whether this is a safe way to do it for **all** v2.2 devices.  It works fine on my HTC Desire, I just don't know if there are any landscape by default v2.2 devices (for example) that this might not work with.

Comment: The API is generic. If it works fine on yours, it should work fine in every other 2.2 model. and yes, in my opinion (6 months programming) it's pretty safe do it that way.